# JSF: How to attach an actionListener to component created programatically?

Tags: jsf

I have to create some commandLinks dynamically and attach some action listener to it, So I've put `<h:panelGrid>` on the JSP page and used such code to add the commandLinks and to assign action listeners to:

```
public ManagedBean(){
 List<UIComponenet> child = panelGrid.getChilderen();
 list.clear();

 List<MyClass> myList = getSomeList();

 for (MyClass myObj : myList){
   FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentContext();
   HtmlCommandLink cmdLink = (HtmlCommandLink) ctx.getApplication.createComponent(HtmlCommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);
   cmdLink.setValue(myObj.getName());
   cmdLink.setActionLinstner(new ActionListener(){
     public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException{
       System.out.println (">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>I am HERE ");
     }
   });
   child.add(cmdLink);
 }
}
```

But unfortunately, when I press this commandLinks, an exception thrown! How can I add component event listeners at runtime?

(Note, the code above my contain syntax/compilation errors as I just wrote).

Comment: Don't have the stack trace right now, but Is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you need to manually assign ID to any dynamically created `UINamingContainer`,  `UIInput` and `UICommand` components. Otherwise JSF can't locate them in the component tree based on the request parameters, because it wouldn't match the autogenerated ID's.

Thus, at least do:

```
HtmlCommandLink link = new HtmlCommandLink();
link.setId("linkId");
// ...
```

Second, you're supposed to create an `ActionListener` as [`MethodExpression`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/el/MethodExpression.html) as follows:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
MethodExpression methodExpression = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
    context.getELContext(), "#{bean.actionListener}", null, new Class[] { ActionEvent.class });

link.addActionListener(new MethodExpressionActionListener(methodExpression));
// ...
```

...and of course have the following method in the backing bean class behind `#{bean}`:

```
public void actionListener(ActionEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

All the above dynamic stuff basically does the same as the following raw JSF tag:

```
<h:commandLink id="linkId" actionListener="#{bean.actionListener}" />
```

Comment: Well done, thanks too much:)
But I noticed that, the first click on any command link doesn't work, only from the second click the listener start in invocation.

Comment: Give all parent `UINamingContainer` (e.g. `UIForm`, `UIData`, etc) elements a **fixed** ID (either dynamically or statically) and do **not** use MyFaces/Tomahawk's `prependId="false"` --if any used.

Comment: @BalusC what if I have a UIComponent button = viewRoot.findComponent("save"); ? How do I add actionListener to that? Do I still use MethodExpression? It is asking me that I have to cast to UICommand but I get an error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
Transient components do not work with actionListeners.
Do not call

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setTransient(true);`
or
`component.setTransient(true);`

As soon as I removed it, it was OK.